# Can I create a long lasting anonymous user in Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I didn't get this from reading the guide or docs. Can I use anonymous authentication to create a user session that will be functional for a long period of time (say 10 years)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure. Just set the session length in the Login & Auth tab of your app's dashboard and don't call `unauth()`.

Comment: Do sessions survive app restarts? I'm using the android SDK.